# imacro loop from csv

Tags: csv, imacros

I am trying to run a macro that will log into an account and make some changes and then log into another account number and do the same changes.

So far I am able to log into the account and make the change but I am not able to have my macro pull the next account id from the csv and continue on. I think it can be done with a loop some how but im not certain.

I can't post the exact info for two reasons. 1. its company internal and 2. they block access to forums at work. So i'm going to write something  up similar as what im needing to do is log into an account, do something and then log into another account and do the same thing.

Lets just say as an example that I wanted to log into my lowes account and make a payment then log out and make a payment on my other lowes account.

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE Datasource.csv
SET !VAR1{{!COL1}}
SET !VAR2{{!COL2}}

URL GOTO=url here

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:consumerLoginForm ATTR=NAME:userId CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:url here 
SET !ENCRYPTION NO 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:consumerLoginForm ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT={{!VAR2}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:url here 
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Make<SP>a<SP>Payment
```

I know I can use {{!COL1}} to call the first column, and {{!COL2}} for the second column. That gets my account and password. So how do I get it to go back through and hit row 2 and do the same thing over again?

Ok I figured it out now. My next issue is I want a html form which I have made with two input boxes. I would like to enter the account credentials in them and have the iMacros Script run and include those inputs as the variables.

Comment: View how you can use the `!LOOP` variable in the 'Loop-Csv-2-Web.iim' macro from the default 'Demo-Firefox' folder. (Obviously, it must be played in loop mode.)

Comment: Thanks that works . I updated the issue

Comment: If you use 'iMacros for Firefox', there's no need of html forms because you can invoke a dialogue having two necessary inputs directly from the macro. Contact me via e-mail (see it on my profile page) and I'll try to help you out with this code.

Comment: I emailed u. Thanks